# Eliminar objetos que no existan en otro array con el mismo id

Tags: javascript

Tengo un objeto genérico (`availableProducts`), cuyas propiedades son arrays de objetos de distintos tipos (`type1`, `type2`, ...).

Por otro lado tengo un array de objetos específico (`specificProducts`).

Necesito que si un objeto del tipo que sea (contenido en `type1`, `type2`, ...) NO existe con ese `ID` en el array específico (`specificProducts`), se elimine de `availableProducts`.

He conseguido hacer lo contrario, que si existe, lo elimine, pero al revés la comprobación es distinta, me he bloqueado y no sé muy bien cómo hacer esa comprobación.

Os pongo mi código:

```js
var availableProducts = {type1:[],type2:[],type3:[]};

product1 = {id:"8sdgs7dfgg7e", name:"A1", description:"desc1"};
product2 = {id:"h78sghfg7asd", name:"A2", description:"desc2"};
product3 = {id:"hay78d7887ss", name:"A3", description:"desc3"};
product4 = {id:"fa67dgshgfsc", name:"A4", description:"desc4"};

availableProducts.type1.push(product1);
availableProducts.type2.push(product2);
availableProducts.type2.push(product3);
availableProducts.type3.push(product4);

console.log("availableProducts antes", availableProducts);

var specificProducts = [];
productData1 = {ref:"001", id:"hay78d7887ss", brand:"brand1"};
productData2 = {ref:"002", id:"h78sghfg7asd", brand:"brand2"};
specificProducts.push(productData1);
specificProducts.push(productData2);

console.log("specificProducts antes", specificProducts);


for (var product in availableProducts){

    for (var i=0; i < availableProducts[product].length; i++) {

      for (var j=0; j < specificProducts.length; j++) {

        if (availableProducts[product][i] != undefined) {

          if (availableProducts[product][i].id == specificProducts[j].id) {

            console.log(availableProducts[product][i].id + " is the same as "+ specificProducts[j].id);

          } else {

            console.log(availableProducts[product][i].id + " is different as "+ specificProducts[j].id);
            availableProducts[product].splice(i,1);
            //delete availableProducts[product][i];
            //elimina todo y deja vacíos los arrays, cómo hago esto de otra forma??
          }

        }

      }

    }  
}

console.log("availableProducts después", availableProducts);
```

Al final si son distintos me vacía todo los datos como podéis ver, me imagino que sea porque en el bucle for va comprobando uno a uno. No sé cómo solucionar esto, gracias.

Comment: ¿Pudiste revisar las respuestas que te proporcionamos para ver si alguna soluciona tu problema?

Comment: Siii, disculpa el retraso, funciona perfectamente!! Muy bien explicado y solucioné mi problema, gracias!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema que sufres es debido a que aunque coincida con uno de los `ID`, en cuando compruebe si coincide con otro diferente dicha comprobación fallará y el registro será eliminado.

Para solucionarlo debemos usar una bandera de `encontrado` que por defecto estará en `false` y que sólo cambiará en cuanto uno de los `ID` coincida.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo de cómo implementarlo:

```js
var availableProducts = {type1:[{id:"8sdgs7dfgg7e", name:"A1", description:"desc1"}],type2:[{id:"h78sghfg7asd", name:"A2", description:"desc2"},{id:"hay78d7887ss", name:"A3", description:"desc3"}],type3:[{id:"fa67dgshgfsc", name:"A4", description:"desc4"}]};
console.log("availableProducts antes", availableProducts);

var specificProducts = [{ref:"001", id:"hay78d7887ss", brand:"brand1"},{ref:"002", id:"h78sghfg7asd", brand:"brand2"}];

for (let product in availableProducts) {
  for (let i = 0; i < availableProducts[product].length ; i++) {
    /* Controlamos que haya sido encontrado o no */
    let encontrado = false;
    console.log(availableProducts[product][i].id);
    for (let j = 0; j < specificProducts.length; j++) {
      if (availableProducts[product][i].id == specificProducts[j].id) {
        console.log('Encontrado', availableProducts[product][i].id, specificProducts[j].id);
        /* ¡Encontrado! */
        encontrado = true;
        /* No es necesario seguir buscando otros IDs */
        break;
      }
    }
    /* Si la bandera de "encontrado" no ha sido modificada es porque no se encontró el ID */
    if (encontrado === false) {
      console.log('Borrado', availableProducts[product][i].id);
      availableProducts[product].splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log("availableProducts después", availableProducts);
```

---

Versión mejorada:

```js
var availableProducts = {type1:[{id:"8sdgs7dfgg7e", name:"A1", description:"desc1"}],type2:[{id:"h78sghfg7asd", name:"A2", description:"desc2"},{id:"hay78d7887ss", name:"A3", description:"desc3"}],type3:[{id:"fa67dgshgfsc", name:"A4", description:"desc4"}]};
console.log("availableProducts antes", availableProducts);

var specificProducts = [{ref:"001", id:"hay78d7887ss", brand:"brand1"},{ref:"002", id:"h78sghfg7asd", brand:"brand2"}];

Reflect.ownKeys(availableProducts).forEach(product => {
  availableProducts[product].forEach((elemento, i) => {
    /* Buscamos el id en specificProducts */
    if (specificProducts.find(existente => existente.id == elemento.id) === undefined) {
      availableProducts[product].splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
});

console.log("availableProducts después", availableProducts);
```

Comment: En los loops, pidiendo .length en cada iteración no es óptimo.

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo , mi primer código es el del OP corregido, explicándole por qué no le funcionaba correctamente. Creo que es lo más correcto y útil para él. El segundo es mi sugerencia.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi solución. Por favor lea los comentarios en el código

```js
//tu código

var availableProducts = {type1:[],type2:[],type3:[]};

product1 = {id:"8sdgs7dfgg7e", name:"A1", description:"desc1"};
product2 = {id:"h78sghfg7asd", name:"A2", description:"desc2"};
product3 = {id:"hay78d7887ss", name:"A3", description:"desc3"};
product4 = {id:"fa67dgshgfsc", name:"A4", description:"desc4"};

availableProducts.type1.push(product1);
availableProducts.type2.push(product2);
availableProducts.type2.push(product3);
availableProducts.type3.push(product4);


var specificProducts = [];
productData1 = {ref:"001", id:"hay78d7887ss", brand:"brand1"};
productData2 = {ref:"002", id:"h78sghfg7asd", brand:"brand2"};
specificProducts.push(productData1);
specificProducts.push(productData2);




for (let type in availableProducts){
// para cada tipo
 availableProducts[type].forEach((p,i)=>{
 // recupera el id
 let thisId = p.id;
 // establece una valiavle que sea false
 let ok = false;
 // iterrar specificProducts
   for(let i = 0; i < specificProducts.length; i++){
     if(thisId == specificProducts[i].id){
       // si encuentro el mismo id salgo del bucle o sea: lo he encontrado y no tengo que hacer nada
       ok = true;
       break
       }
   }
   
  // si no lo he encontrado lo elimino de availableProducts
  if(ok == false) {availableProducts[type].splice(i,1)}
})

}


console.log(availableProducts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución:

```js
var availableProducts = {type1:[],type2:[],type3:[]};

product1 = {id:"8sdgs7dfgg7e", name:"A1", description:"desc1"};
product2 = {id:"h78sghfg7asd", name:"A2", description:"desc2"};
product3 = {id:"hay78d7887ss", name:"A3", description:"desc3"};
product4 = {id:"fa67dgshgfsc", name:"A4", description:"desc4"};

availableProducts.type1.push(product1);
availableProducts.type2.push(product2);
availableProducts.type2.push(product3);
availableProducts.type3.push(product4);

var specificProducts = [];
productData1 = {ref:"001", id:"hay78d7887ss", brand:"brand1"};
productData2 = {ref:"002", id:"h78sghfg7asd", brand:"brand2"};
specificProducts.push(productData1);
specificProducts.push(productData2);

console.log(availableProducts)

// let's go
Object.keys(availableProducts).forEach((type) => {
  availableProducts[type] = availableProducts[type].reduce((acc, item) => {
    specificProducts.forEach(specificProduct => {
      if (specificProduct.id === item.id) acc.push(item)
    })
    return acc
  }, [])
})

console.log(availableProducts)
```

Comment: En esta solución estás usando dos matrices auxiliares. Por un lado `specificProductsIds` y por otro una copia filtrada de la matriz original llamada `availableProductsResult` en la que vuelcas los elementos de la original que tienen los `ID` listados. ¿Necesitas realmente usar memoria adicional para almacenar matrices auxiliares? Si necesitas mantener una copia de la matriz original entiendo el uso de `availableProductsResult`, pero `specificProductsIds` te la puedes ahorrar.

Comment: obvio que las puedo ahorrar, solo intentaba ser explícito para quien hizo el post.

Comment: Bueno, poner como único comentario **// let's go** no me pareció muy explicito. Pensé que sería buena idea sugerirte evitar el uso de la menos necesaria, pero es tu respuesta y eres libre de mantenerla como está.